# WP Rewrite issue

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to build this structure:

for single page:

```
www.example.com/london/restaurants/monrooe/
```

where:

- "london" is a query var
- "restaurants" is a category
- "monrooe" is the post name.

How can I do it?

That's code I have so far:

```
function setup_city_var($vars){     
  $vars[] = "city";
  return $vars;
}


function create_custom_rewrite_rules() {

  global $wp_rewrite;
  $rewrite_tag = '%city%';

  // Add the rewrite tokens
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( $rewrite_tag, '(.+?)', 'city=' );

  // Define the custom permalink structure
  $rewrite_keywords_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . "$rewrite_tag/%pagename%";

  // Generate the rewrite rules
  $new_rule = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_keywords_structure );

  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rule + $wp_rewrite->rules;

  return $wp_rewrite->rules;
} // End create_custom_rewrite_rules()
```

It doesn't work, it's a 404

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you flushed your rewrite rules (visit permalinks admin page)? Further, questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.